# Difference in lists / trouble plotting

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, matplotlib

I have imported a list via a csv with following code

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dates = []

with open('Data3.txt') as csvDataFile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvDataFile,quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    for row in csvReader:
        dates.append(row)

data=np.array(dates)
print(data[:,0], data[:,1])
```

Printing it leads to the following two sets

```
['0.13' '0.27' '0.4' ... '8737.6' '8737.73' '8737.87'] 
['0.022' '0.0205' '0.019' ... '7.1187' '6.7994' '7.2403']
```

Trying to plot this is impossible with

```
plt.plot(data[:,0], data[:,1])
plt.show()
```

So I have set up another array with

```
cplr=[0.01828922,  0.01972157,  0.02342053,  0.25928021,
0.26352547,  0.26883406]
```

This one I can easily plot

Now I wonder why when printing it, the first set has ' around the number, and the 2nd not. How can I make the data "plotable"?

```
['0.13' '0.27' '0.4' ... '8737.6' '8737.73' '8737.87'] 
['0.022' '0.0205' '0.019' ... '7.1187' '6.7994' '7.2403']

[0.01828922, 0.01972157, 0.02342053, 0.25928021, 0.26352547, 0.26883406]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the format of `Data3.txt` you might use [`np.loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) which does the conversion from string to float and returns a numpy array.

Answer (score 2):

> Now I wonder why when printing it, the first set has ' around the number, and the 2nd not.

The return type is `<class 'str'>`, that's why you can not plot the data. It must be numerical type for `matplotlib` to plot it.

> How can I make the data "plotable"?

You have to typecast into a numerical type, in this case, `<class 'float'>`. You can iterate over each elements, or easier, use `map` function and do `float()`.

Comment: `np.array(map(float, dates))`

this worked for me - thank you!